# html editor properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

I used the AjaxControlToolkit html editor on my page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<cc1:Editor ID="txtjobdesc" runat="server" AutoFocus="False"  />
```

I sent the values to the database as `txtjobdesc.Content.Tostring();`

But, if I type just a paragraph in the editor it displays the same Description.
If i use any Bullets and Highlighted words it displays the bulleted words, Overlapping words below.

How do I make it display as a html description?

pls help me out..

Comment: Is the html on the database and the problem is with rendering or the text saved to database doesn't is html?

Comment: ya the prob is while rendering the text from the db if any bullets over ther it is coming at the top of words already displayed

Comment: Maybe this can help. http://forums.asp.net/p/1485204/3483151.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Send editor output to database after encoding it as **Server.HTMLencode(editor.content)** and get back it as **Server.HTMLDecode(editor.content)**

I'm damn sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

if using sql set the datattype of the column to text. Sql2005/2008, i am sure . earlier version not sure

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do this: You may use NText SQL type or use Nvarchar(MAX) data type, which I believe the later one is so much better as it behaves as a Nvarchar type and provides better string manipulation. Otherwise, the varchar has capacity of at max 8000 bytes.